# Inline figure saved as PNG from Jupyter notebook shows black margin in IrfanView

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

This minimal example (as the only cell of am ipython/yupiter notebook)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.savefig('test.png')
```

yields the expected empty plot in the code cell but a PNG file that IrfanView presents with a black margin instead of the ticks and tick labels. <s>Inspection in IrfanView ruled out a problem of transparency.</s> I have also tried `fig.tight_layout()` and `plt.savefig`.

Versions are

- Windows 10
- IrfanView 4.44 - 64 bit
- kernel: 6.2.0
- matplotlib: 3.3.4
- python: 3.9.0

EDIT: SVG and PDF are fine, even PNG looks fine in Paint, while paint.net reveals a transparent background at the margin. My previous inspection with IrfanView consisted of selecting the white of the inner area as transparent color, which obviously changed the formerly transparent background of the margin to black :-(

EDIT 2: IrfanView can be configured to show transparent pixels in other colors than black (Options > Properties > Viewing > Main Window Color), but that setting is applied to transparent pixels only on reload/reopening.

Comment: I got the expected output with python 3.7, maybe it is something to do with the python version. Do you obtain the same result even changing the output format? e.g. try saving in SVG or even PDF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what your code produces as test.png for me:

[image]

Perhaps you can post your figure to be clearer what the problem is. What backend are you using? Find out with:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.get_backend()
```

Maybe using `set_facecolor` could help?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.patch.set_facecolor('white')
fig.savefig('test.png')
```

Comment: Output: 'module://ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline'. `set_facecolor('white')` helped. Thank you, Shall I report a bug?

Comment: I don't know because I'm not sure what exactly the problem is in the end. I have the feeling the problem just was the transparency (which got removed with `set_facecolor`) and how you opened the resulting PNG.

Comment: The inline backend violates the Principle of Least Surprise by exporting diagrams with transparent parts, when other backends (and other programs used for plotting, like Gnuplot, Excel) do not.